# Mongoose Model.save() returning undefined in mocha/chai /GET :id test

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am testing out my routes folder with mocha/chai but I am hitting a wall when it comes to the /get id test.

I am creating a new category (test) and want that to save before I request the endpoint with ChaiHttp. However, my error keeps returning as "cannot read property '_id' of undefined" as below

```
Routes
    /GET categories
      ✓ should GET all the categories (84ms)
    /GET/:id categories
{
  _id: 600972de84fe2307c0f2f351,
  name: 'test',
  icon: 'test-icon',
  color: '#fffff'
}
undefined
      1) it should GET a category given the id


  1 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1) Routes
       /GET/:id categories
         it should GET a category given the id:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Below is my test for the /get Route :Id

```
describe("/GET/:id categories", () => {
    it("it should GET a category given the id", (done) => {
      let category = new Category({
        name: 'test',
        icon: 'test-icon',
        color: '#fffff',
      })
      console.log(category)
      category.save((err, c) => {
        console.log(c)
        const id = c._id 
        chai
          .request(`${process.env.BASE_URL}${process.env.API_URL}`)
          .get("/categories/" + id)
          .send(c)
          .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.body).to.be.an("object")
            expect(res).to.have.property("statusCode", 200)
            expect(res.body).to.have.property("_id").eql(id)
            done()
          })
      })
    })
  })
```

the console.log before the category.save() shows the code below, returning exactly the same as it is in Postman requests.

```
{
  _id: 600972de84fe2307c0f2f351,
  name: 'test',
  icon: 'test-icon',
  color: '#fffff'
}
```

However, the Model.save() promise does not seem to be saving or passing this into the chai Request.

I am running a test database within my App.js as follows.

```
// Database
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  const mongoUriTest = process.env.TEST_DATABASE
  mongoose
    .connect(mongoUriTest, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Successfully connected to Test_Database')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
} else {
  const mongoUri = process.env.DATABASE
  mongoose
    .connect(mongoUri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Successfully connected to Database')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(err)` instead of `console.log(c)`.

Comment: @hoangdv MongooseError: Operation `categories.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms. 

Cheers for the tip! Now just gotta research out how to solve this when database is connected fine.